# Is it possible to make the Bash "source" command keep environment variables passed in manually?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file `.env` containing environment variables, e.g.:

```
TZ=UTC
NODE_ENV=development
```

Then, in my Bash scripts, I use:

```
set -o allexport; source .env; set +o allexport
```

This loads all the environment variables from `.env`.

However, if I manually pass environment variables to the script, they get overwritten by `source`. E.g. if I run `NODE_ENV=production ./script.sh`, I'd like it to keep `NODE_ENV=production` instead of using `NODE_ENV=development` from `.env`. How could I do this?

I'm using Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is. But you can modify your .env file as follows to prevent it from overwriting `NODE_ENV`.

```
TZ=UTC
NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development}
```

Comment: That means the person handling the .env needs to know about that "let's not overwrite that variable" constraint...

Answer (score 13):

Store environment "for later", source the file, then restore environment.

```
curenv=$(declare -p -x)
source .env
eval "$curenv"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider the following cases:

1. A variable X **is already defined**, and the sourced file should then **not touch** it.
2. A variable X **is already defined**, and the sourced file should then ensure that it is **put into the environment**.
3. A variable X is **not yet defined**, and the sourced file then should **create it**.
4. A variable X is **not yet defined**, and the sourced file then should **create it** and **put it into the environment**.

If you want **1+3**, this is the simplest:

```
: ${X:=value}
```

The `:` is simply the bash no-op command and the `:=` ensures that `X` gets the value if it is not defined yet. The export status (i.e. *in environment* or *not in environment*) is **not** affected.

If you want the combination **2+4**, you could do either

```
export X=${X:-value}
```

or

```
: ${X:=value}
export X
```

The `export` statement ensures that the variable is in the environment afterwards, even if it was not in the environment before.

For my taste, the latter variant is more verbose, but clearer to read.

In theory you could also ask for the combination **1+3**, i.e. not modify the environmental state of the variable, if it is defined already, but create it in the environment, if it is not defined. I can't think of a reasonable use case for this, but if you need, I can amend my answer and provide a solution for this as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because the `source` command is invoked after passing external variables.

To accomplish that a workaround may require some coding:

1. Don't use `source` command.
2. Load `.env` file content and parse it into an associative array.
3. For each variable it contains, check if it is already assigned (externally).
4. If it not assigned, assign the value into the array.